# The output is a vey very large matrix using bigmemory

Tags: ehcache-bigmemory

I'm using bigmemory i want to calculate w.
my v length is 478000 and k length is 240500.
The two matrix multiplication is w very large I run the code by loop still is running is not finished yet and i don't know if will give me the result or no.
I'm trying to calculate without the for loop. I got error.
Please any help to correct my code r make it fast.

```
    v <-read.big.matrix('v.dat',type='double')
    k <-read.big.matrix('k.dat',type='double')
    m=length(v);
    n=length(k);
    w <-filebacked.big.matrix(length(v),length(k),type="double",backingfile="w.bin",descriptorfile="w.desc")
    start <- Sys.time()
    w <- as.big.matrix(2*cos(0.001*v[]%*%t(k[]))-2)
    Sys.time() - start

    # for(i in 1:m)
   # {

           # for(j in 1:n)
           # {
                   # w[i,j]=2*cos(dt*v[i]*k[j])-2
           # }
   # }
```

Thanks.